# Loading a standard layout into a ListActivity

Tags: android, listview, android-layout

I'd like my App to show a warning message if there are no elements to load on a ListActivity; so I thought to write this on the onResume event:

```
if(elementsToLoad.size()==0) setContentView (alternative layout); else loadList();
```

but it crashes...How could I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use an empty view. See `setEmptyView(View emptyView)` method from ListView. Or you can add view to your layout with id @android:id/empty and ListView will show it for you, if list is empty.

Comment: +1, totally agree with @Tomas , here is an example for the same: http://goo.gl/qBjhV